# Changing CGRectMake to draw a circle around animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using that code to put an circle-animation with touch functions, but the result is that my animation is a circle and its 'closed' by black rectangle with black borders.

```
Anim1 *anim1 = [[Anim1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,45, 282, 282)];
```

how can i change it so it will be in a circle by the animation size?

Comment: You might need to add some more info !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the answer...
it's:

```
 [anim1.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]];
 [anim1 setOpaque:NO];
```

The `[anim1 setOpaque:NO]`; do all the work without it you get only colored background.